Can we define different filters for different category using Algolia?
I am building a e-commerce app. Top level category can be Men , Women , Home Decor. Inside this there is sub category and sub-sub category. Each sub sub category can have different attributes. How can we acheive this through algolia. Example:- for tshirts the filters would be like colour , material, size . For home decor it may have different attributes for filters. Can anyone suggest any solution. I am using java for backend and flutter for frontend.
I am thinking to built a index with hierarchical categories and facets. Am I in right direction?
